# Oracle SQL GROUP BY clause containing joins

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, group-by

I'm having issues writing this query correctly. Below is the goal, my current query, and attached are the scripts to build and populate the database. Thanks for any assistance!

> For each DVD in the catalog, display it’s title, length, release_date, and how many times it has been checked out by all customers across all libraries. Include those that have not been checked out yet (display as 0). Sort results by title.

```
SELECT C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE, COUNT(T.TRANSACTION_ID)
FROM catalog_item C
INNER JOIN dvd D ON D.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN physical_item P ON P.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction T ON T.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = P.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
GROUP BY C.TITLE;
```

Run first: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PYAZV4KIfZtxP4eQn35zsczySsxDM7ls

Run second: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pAzWmJqvD3o3n6YJqVUM6TtxDafKGd3f

**EDIT**
I've gotten the query working but haven't figured out how to get DVDs with zero checkouts to show up. Below is my updated query.

```
SELECT C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE, COUNT(T.TRANSACTION_ID)
FROM catalog_item C
INNER JOIN dvd D ON D.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN physical_item P ON P.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction T ON T.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = P.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
GROUP BY C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE;
```

**SOLVED**
Figured out the issue with GMB's help. Final query below!

```
SELECT C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE, NVL(COUNT(T.TRANSACTION_ID), 0) AS NUMBER_OF_CHECKOUTS
FROM catalog_item C
INNER JOIN dvd D ON D.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN physical_item P ON P.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN transaction T ON T.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = P.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
GROUP BY C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE
ORDER BY C.TITLE;
```

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query sure looks better than the first one, as it has the correct `GROUP BY` clause.

It is hard to provide a 100% sure response without seeing the full tables structures, however if you are still missing records with 0 checkouts in the output, it means that one of your `INNER JOIN`s is not matching. In other words, you have DVDs in your catalog that are either not present in the `dvd` table, or not present in the `physical_item` table. As both tables look like referential table, this could indicate a discrepency in your data. I would recommend to change all `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s to work around this issue.

Also please note that if no checkout happened for a DVD, expression `COUNT(T.TRANSACTION_ID)` will yield `NULL` : hence you want to wrap it in a `NVL` function to handle this case.

New query :

```
SELECT C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE, NVL(COUNT(T.TRANSACTION_ID), 0)
FROM catalog_item C
LEFT JOIN dvd D ON D.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN physical_item P ON P.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = C.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN transaction T ON T.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = P.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
GROUP BY C.TITLE, D.LENGTH, C.RELEASE_DATE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tweaked it a little bit and edited my question to incorporate your feedback. The first join should be INNER as we only want DVDs and a LEFT JOIN would also pull books. Thank you again!

Comment: Welcome @RyanCohan, glad that it helped out !

Comment: `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.  The `NVL()` is unnecessary.

Comment: There is an assumption here that `T.TRANSACTION_ID` is declared as `NOT NULL`, or each non-`NULL` value represents a valid checkout (if `NULL`s are allowed).